Puede aparecer mi aplicación de expo en el listado para compartir de otra aplicación?
Quiero saber si es posible que por ejemplo:
Estoy viendo fotos en mi galería y la quiero subir una imagen a mi aplicación, al momento de presionar compartir y se abra el listado de compartir, aparezca mi aplicación y yo ya manejarlo desde mi aplicación de expo utilizando React Navigation para mandarlo a cierta parte de mi aplicación con un formulario para subirla.
¿Es posible realizar estas acciones?
